# Git using strange paths

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have no idea what is going on here.  I am using OS X and git 2.2.1 with integration in IntelliJ 141.1532.

This is the third time this week that this has happened and I have no idea where it is breaking.  After a merge it is showing files that can't exist at all.

```
"document/src/main/java\aalert/controllers/responses/AlertResultIndexFilterResponse.java"
```

What is that `\a`??

Comment: I suggest using git from the command line to figure out if it is git or the IntelliJ integration.